# Energy Dissipated in Perfectly Inelastic Collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, collision

I was recently going over an AP physics C exam question, and I don't really buy their solution for one of the problems. The specific problem is *Mech 1. part e* of [this test](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/apc/ap11_frq_physics_cm.pdf), and the solutions are listed [here](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/apc/ap11_physics_c_mech_scoring_guidelines.pdf). For those of you who don't want to read the problem, the question is basically asking that if you shoot a bullet into a wood block, and the wood exerts an average force of $F_b$ on the bullet, and the bullet travels a distance $d_n$ into the block, is the heat energy dissipated equal to $F_b \cdot d_n$, assuming that the block is **free to move** along the surface? I'd assume not because some of that work is converted into kinetic energy of the block. I may be misinterpreting the problem, but I believe that if the heat dissipated is not $F_b d_n$, then the solution they gave is wrong.

Comment: "I'd assume not because some of that work is converted into kinetic energy of the block". Isn't the kinetic energy of the block dissipated as heat due to the friction work done by the table on the block bringing it to a stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a general case, where the block moves a distance $x_2$ after some time, and the bullet moves with $x_1$. During this time an equal and opposite force $F$ is applied to the bullet and the block.

[image: fig1]

The work done to the block is clearly $F\,x_2$ and the work the bullet does is $F\,x_1$. Work causes a change in kinetic energy on each body

$$ \Delta KE_1 = \frac{1}{2} m_1 v_{\rm bullet}^2 - \frac{1}{2} m_1 v_{\rm block}^2 = F x_1$$
$$ \Delta KE_2 = \frac{1}{2} m_2 v_{\rm block}^2 = F x_2$$

The energy lost is the quantity of work done by the bullet, that did not go into the block as kinetic energy

$$ \Delta KE_1 = E_{\rm loss} + \Delta KE_2 $$

or

$$E_{\rm loss} = \Delta KE_1 - \Delta KE_2 = F x_1 - F x_2 = F\, d_n $$

Answer (score 2):

This is really a comment, but it is too long for a comment.

For all these energy-loss collision problems it is quickest to use the very useful (and easy to prove) *reduced-mass* identity
$$
\frac 12 m_1 {\bf v}_1^2 + \frac 12 m_2 {\bf v}_2^2 = \frac 12 \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}|{\bf v}_1- {\bf v}_2|^2 + \frac 12 (m_1+m_2) {\bf V}_{\rm c of m}^2.
$$

This is because  $$
V_{\rm c of m}= \frac{m_1{\bf v}_1+m_2 {\bf v}_2}{m_1+m_2}
$$
is unaffected by the collision, while the change in the relative speed $|{\bf v}_1- {\bf v}_2|$, the only thing affected by the degree of inelasticity, is obtained directly from the coefficient of restitution.